# read sessionScope variable in Java?

Tags: java, xpages

In my xpages application I set some variables that are valid for the session of the user in a sessionScope variable.

I would like to use these user settings in my Java classes.

Is possible to read a specific sessionScope variable in my java class and how should I do this?

Comment: What other java class? Is it a bean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil` class. It comes with static methods to access the scope variables. You can get a map of all session scope variables like this:

```
Map sessionScope = ExtLibUtil.getSessionScope();
String yourVar = (String) sessionScope.get("varName");
```